# MobileFirst 7.1 build all environment is not creating android folder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-security, mobilefirst-studio

i have created the sample app 0n mobilefirst 7.1 with mac 10.12.5 java 1.8 eclipse mars, once i have created project added the android and ios environment after done build all environment ,ideally it should create separate android folder for that but its not creating any separate android folder , please any solution really appreciated

Comment: What if you try an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: i am using MAC 10.12.5, tried the keplar and Juno , while opening it get crashes , so i have installed mars

Comment: Since you have not provided any further details such as error messages or logs, I assume it is missing ADT plugin for eclipse. Verify if your eclipse has ADT plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the issue is missing "Android Developer Tools" Plugin in your Eclipse. This is required to create the Android native project, when you add Android environment.
Verify its installation.